# How to connect ethernet shield for arduino

Tags: web-services, ethernet, arduino-uno, iot

I'm new to IoT and I am trying to connect web service through a arduino. I think it is possible using Ethernet could you please explain how to connect Ethernet to arduino and how access through it.What are the steps i should follow, if there any other way to do it let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the ethernet/wifi shield hardware for your Arduino?  Here is some [sample code](https://github.com/ibm-messaging/iot-arduino/blob/master/samples/quickstartwifishield/quickstartwifishield.ino) for how to connect arduino using IBM Bluemix IOT services.

Comment: Thank you so much. Actually I don't have any. I'm planning to buy one so I just plan to buy one. If it is easy to configure wifi shield I'll go for it. :) how to connect those two.

Comment: I suggest you check the Arduino website.  You can purchase an ethernet shield and the website has instructions for how to connect:  https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoEthernetShield